# getting parameters from url in angularjs controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the folowing link in asp.net mvc:

```
@Html.ActionLink(user.Alias.ToUpper(), "Employee", new { controller = "User", id = user.Alias, area = "Organization" }
```

(.../Organization/Employee/someId#/)

how can I get id value in angularjs controller?

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $location, User) {

    $scope.user = User.get({ id: ??? })
})
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are you using ng-route or ui-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ng-route`, use `$routeParams.someId`.

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get({ id: $routeParams.someId });
})
```

If you are using `ui-route`, use `$stateParams.someId`.

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get({ id: $stateParams.someId });
})
```

Comment: nope. Still not working. Maybe problem is in the way I'm passing parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$routeParams` See this example: https://thinkster.io/egghead/routeparams-api/

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, User) {

     $scope.someid = $stateParams.someId
```

})

Comment: neither $stateParams and $routeParams cannot get the value

Comment: someId is an actual value