# Passing Parameter to a Angular Controller from MVC action link URL

Tags: angularjs, url, model-view-controller

I am new to Angularjs and I am building a ASP.NET MVC 6 application with some Angularjs views, I got an issue to pass parameter from MVC action link to the AngularJS controller, my url from MVC action link is as:http://localhost/Sites/Details/1, in my Details.cshtml page hosting the Angularjs to show Site location maps,

In my MVC Route:

`routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`

In my MVC codes are as:

`public JsonResult GetSiteInfo(int SiteId)
        {
            var sList = _context.Station.Where(s => s.Category.Site.SiteID == SiteId);
            return Json(sList);
        }`

Angularjs codes are as:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps','ngRoute']);
app.controller('mapController', function ($scope, $http,$window, $location, $routeParams, SiteID) {
var sid = SiteID.get({ id: $routeParams.someId });

    //Populate Site location information by site ID
    $http.get('/Sites/GetSiteInfo').
    params: {
            siteId: siteId
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.locations = data.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error');
    });
```

I want to retrieve the siteId parameter from the URL in Angularjs and filter the result, currently I cannot retrieve the parameter from the URl in my Angularjs code, I am not sure what I did wrong, please advise.

**Update:**
I found a resolved similar post from this link, but it seems not work for me,
[getting parameters from url in angularjs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276309/getting-parameters-from-url-in-angularjs-controller),

Answer (score 0):

Try `$routeParams.siteId` in controller.

```
console.log("site id = "+$routeParams.siteId);
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried, it did not work, I have updated my codes, seems still not work